# how to design an interface for a game a.i

Tags: php, interface, artificial-intelligence, game-engine

i would like to design an interface for our a.i class so everbody could implement an a.i and we could let the different implementations fight each other.

what i would like to hear is how to approach something like this?

Is there any best practice? What kind of information do i have to gather?

- A list of possible actions?
- A list of possible events?
- A list of all units and attr?

More information about the game:
We are talking about a battle a.i on a hexagon field. There are x different units with y different properties like dmg, life, movement. The play field has a fixed width / height and some hex fields have properties themself. Giving bonuses and the other way around.

Thx for your time and advice.

Comment: This is a very broad question being asked here, you'd be better off having a go at it and returning if you have a specific issue you cannot resolve. Good luck though, sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1):

What an interesting question.  This calls for advice rather than experience and I will admit that I am good at the former and light on the latter.  Read on at your peril.

First off, if you ahve a working AI class and think it is good then you must, surely, have written at least a small game to use it and test it.  What did you ask yourselves when you wrote it?  Other users will want to make the same assumptions I am sure.

In my experience there are fundamental characteristics of units in hex battle games and you could do a lot worse than look at Traveller, Dungeons and Dragons etc, all of which give detailed characteristics for units, terrain and the effects on movement etc - all of these will need to be taken into consideration.
These units need to work together or separately.
Users like to be able to customise their units.  This means a very complex rdb behind the AI.  It's a bit silly (if amusing) to allow an infantryman to carry a 20mm cannon but he will need a large selection of weapons
The tactics will vary with weapons and eras but there are battle fundamentals.
Would your AI win at Cannae? Crecy? Salamanca? Iwo Jima? Hoth?  how flexible is it?  All these battles have similarities but the differences will make a single AI engine hard to optimise.

The hardest thing in AI is to give units personality.  The best hex game I ever played was Sid Meier's Alpha Centauri - this is a relatively dated game now but is probably a good benchmark for units with simple personalities - can your class beat that?  Nothing I've seen on xbox is notably beyond this rather crude intelligence level (skyrim is close but still awfully formulaic) However it did give the game a remarkable lastability by making it a very different experience if playing as a different 'faction'

The big problem with AIs is that they make certain rather concrete assumptions and, once you have worked those out, they become easy-beats.  Is yours flexible?  even the most dedicated green might consider a nuke if faced with extinction as the alternative after all.

Perhaps you should troll the game forums for issues with AIs.  Ask the players, not the programmers what they want.  The programming is usually fairly simple, once the problem is clearly defined.

From a programming point of view, I would want to be able to set the broad strokes and let the AI handle the rest eg:

I specify the units and their characteristics in detail.
I place the units on the field.
I set routes to objectives for the whole, and within the whole, groups and possibly individual units (unit>group>army hierarchy)
I set triggers for events (reinforcements, mines etc)
The AI goes ahead and wins the battle, making optimal use of terrain along the routes specified, selecting best units for certain tasks and ensuring the objective is achieved.

Of course, the player has to prevent it winning ;-)

Good luck.